# Cordova camera plugin dont work fine on ios8

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios8, cordova-plugins

Hi I'm using Ionic 1 to create mobile app. I use:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
```

It dosent work on iOS 8.
Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried it on other platforms? What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin `cordova-plugin-camera` is not compatible with `iOS8` the version supported is `9.3` or `latest`.